# Auto Increment ID in mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm facing a problem with the auto-increment ID in MySQL and PHP, here's the scene, I created a form that inserts the data to my database. I use a table to see all the data I stored from the form in the .php file. I stored 5 rows of data, when I delete the 3rd row, I noticed that the ID in the 4th row doesn't change to 3. Is there a way to set the Id to replace the deleted row?

Comment: This is a non-issue most of the time and you shouldn't manually try to change it either, it *can* cause issues. The alternative is to display a custom incrementing count for the user but use the ID when actually processing the data, for example, display: 1 (ID: 5), 2 (ID: 12), 3 (ID: 19), 4 (ID: 25), 5 (ID: 54).

Comment: you don't want to do that. As a best practice IDs should never change. Why do you want this behaviour?

Comment: There are good reasons for this. What if you had linked another row in another table to row 4 with id=4. If it changed the id to 3 then the link would get broken

Comment: Let's consider I'm a user of your application. There's a nice joke saved in your database with the id 42 (in fact, this is the best joke of the world). I can access this joke following that url : `www.example.com/article/42` I saved this to my favorites and send it by mail to my friends. There was changes in your DB and some articles were deleted. the IDs changed and my friends don't know why I send them a boring article about <insert boring stuff here>

Comment: To summarise the above examples... IDs are intended to _uniquely identify_ the row in question. They have no other meaning than that. They are not describing ordering, or for the purpose of showing a nice neat, consecutive numbered list. Therefore they should identify that row _forever_ and not change. Otherwise you can never be certain which piece of data the ID is actually referring to, and your whole data model falls apart, mired in the inability to accurately refer to a specific row in the database. Gaps in the numbers are _not_ an issue you need to fix.

Comment: as other told you must not do that, but it depends on your scenario. if in any situation you want it be done try this: `SET @num := 0;
UPDATE your_table SET id = @num := (@num+1);
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT =1;`

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like that you're using that ID in a way that you shouldn't.

As you can read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> When you insert any other value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value. For example:

```
INSERT INTO animals (id,name) VALUES(100,'rabbit');
INSERT INTO animals (id,name) VALUES(NULL,'mouse');
SELECT * FROM animals;
+-----+-----------+
| id  | name      |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 | dog       |
|   2 | cat       |
|   3 | penguin   |
|   4 | lax       |
|   5 | whale     |
|   6 | ostrich   |
|   7 | groundhog |
|   8 | squirrel  |
| 100 | rabbit    |
| 101 | mouse     |
+-----+-----------+
```

... So if it was because you are afraid that some value 'later on' (after the deletion of your 3rd row), will get an ID, that isn't the highest one, then you don't need to fear that.

Please update your question with further information on, why this is a problem, if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: thanks. i  finally understand it, i'm learning with php and mysql since it got me hooked up